# Stripe Refuses to send form data to 'https://hooks.stripe.com/three_d_secure/redirect_complete...'

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use `stripe.confirmCardPayment` to confirm a card payment if the card requires a 3D Secure authentication. The stripe method correctly opens the *3D Secure Test Payment Page*, but when I click on *Complete Authentication* it closes the modal and an error is displayed in the console:

```
[Report Only] Refused to send form data to 'https://hooks.stripe.com/three_d_secure/redirect_complete/***' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "form-action 'self'".
```

My form looks like this:

```html
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <CardElement />
    <button type="submit">Pay</button>
</form>
```

And I have a JavaScript function to handle it:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Send calls to API to receive a checkoutId

    // Call the API to create the subscription
    const { subscription } = await createSubscription(checkoutId) 
    const { status, client_secret } = subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent
    
    if (status === "requires_action") {
        const { error: confirmationError } = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret)

        if (confirmationError) {
            console.error(confirmationError);
            alert('unable to confirm card');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I correctly send the form data to Stripe to validate the 3D Secure authentication?

Comment: Do you have a CSP on your site? You need to add some Stripe-specific directives to it : https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy 
Also can you clarify what the result from confirmCardPayment is? Does it just never return/throw an error/give success?

Comment: I don't have a CSP on my site and I'm testing locally for now. I just checked the result of `confirmCardPayment` and it gives a successful response (it calls Stripe API with a POST request once to confirm the payment intent and once again with a GET request with the key and the client secret as URL params, and this last call returns a JSON object with `status: "succeeded"`).

Comment: If it succeeds I'd be inclined to ignore the error somewhat if it's not visible to the customer or stops them from paying, it might just be something internal to Stripe. I know you often get harmless errors if you have adblockers installed as they tend to block some of the metrics pings that can be made.

Comment: It does stop customers from paying as the status I have when I treat the payment on the server side is unsuccessful...

Comment: Hmm. I'd suggest writing to Stripe's support with full details then!

Comment: If you do not use CSP on the site, it can be published by third-party iframe. Anyway it's `[Report Only]` CSP therefore it block nothing. So it's not a reason for failure observed.